# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached binding ListView AngularJS-WinJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, winjs

While working on a little project for my own use ran into an error while binding an AngularJS array to a WinJS ListView.
I've tried to find help on Google and here, but could not find this error in combination with AngularJS-WinJS and the WinJS ListView.
The error I get in the console log is:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":[{"$id":"1","klantId":"-2096584494","klantNaam":"Test klant","adres":"Dorpstraat 123","plaats":"Ons Dorp"}],"oldVal":["..."]}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}]]
>   http: //errors.angularjs.org /1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…on%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22...%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%5D%5D
>       at angular.js:68
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15934)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
>       at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1679)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4523)
>       at doBootstrap (angular.js:1677)
>       at bootstrap (angular.js:1697)
>       at angularInit (angular.js:1591)
>       at HTMLDocument. (angular.js:29013)
>       at fire (jquery-2.1.4.js:3099)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9292Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16162bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1679invoke @ angular.js:4523doBootstrap @ angular.js:1677bootstrap @ angular.js:1697angularInit @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013fire @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3099self.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3211jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3417completed @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3433
>   angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":[{"$id":"1","klantId":"-2096584494","klantNaam":"Test klant","adres":"Dorpstraat 123","plaats":"Ons Dorp"}],"oldVal":["..."]}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["..."],"oldVal":"..."}]]
>   http: //errors.angularjs.org /1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…on%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22...%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%5D%5D(anonymous function) @ angular.js:68Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15934Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16160bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1679invoke @ angular.js:4523doBootstrap @ angular.js:1677bootstrap @ angular.js:1697angularInit @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013fire @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3099self.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3211jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3417completed @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3433

I'm new to AngularJs and WinJS and I can't figure out to solve this error.
I've narrowed the code to a simple website in 2 files.
In this index.html is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MBS SPA</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/toArrayFilter.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-winjs.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="CustomerOverviewController as custOverview">
   <div class="container">
       <h1>{{custOverview.title}}</h1>
       <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="custOverview.searchInput">
        </div>
        <div id="customerListView">
            <win-list-view item-data-source="custOverview.customerList | filter:custOverview.searchInput | orderBy:'klantNaam'" selection="custOverview.selection" selection-mode="'single'" tap-behavior="'directSelect'" class="listview win-selectionstylefilled">
                <win-item-template>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img class="col-sm-2 smallListCustomerItem-Image" src="Content/images/turbine.png" />
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h4 class="win-h4">{{item.data.klantNaam}}</h4>
                            <h6 class="win-h6">{{item.data.adres}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="win-h6">{{item.data.plaats}}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </win-item-template>
                <win-list-layout></win-list-layout>
            </win-list-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the app.js file I have the following script:

```
angular.module('app', ['winjs']);
angular.module('app').controller("CustomerOverviewController", function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Klanten';
    vm.searchInput = '';
    vm.customerList = [{ "$id": "1", "klantId": "-2096584494", "klantNaam": "Test klant", "adres": "Dorpstraat 123", "plaats": "Ons Dorp" }];
    vm.selection = [];
});
```

When I change my code to the solution suggested in the [link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms) in the error message I get another error.
The changed code in the app is:

```
angular.module('app', ['winjs']);
angular.module('app').controller("CustomerOverviewController", function () {
    var vm = this;
    var customers = [{ "$id": "1", "klantId": "-2096584494", "klantNaam": "Test klant", "adres": "Dorpstraat 123", "plaats": "Ons Dorp" }];
    vm.title = 'Klanten';
    vm.searchInput = '';
    vm.customerList = function () {
        return customers;
    };
    vm.selection = [];
});
```

The new error message is:

> Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: function () errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/filter/notarray?p0=function%20()
>       at /Scripts/angular.js:68:12
>       at /Scripts/angular.js:18454:31
>       at fn (eval at  (/Scripts/angular.js:13365:15), :4:407)
>       at /Scripts/angular.js:8898:50
>       at forEach (/Scripts/angular.js:354:20)
>       at initializeDirectiveBindings (/Scripts/angular.js:8852:7)
>       at nodeLinkFn (/Scripts/angular.js:8280:39)
>       at compositeLinkFn (/Scripts/angular.js:7731:13)
>       at compositeLinkFn (/Scripts/angular.js:7734:13)
>       at compositeLinkFn (/Scripts/angular.js:7734:13)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9292Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16157bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1679invoke @ angular.js:4523doBootstrap @ angular.js:1677bootstrap @ angular.js:1697angularInit @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013fire @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3099self.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3211jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3417completed @ jquery-2.1.4.js:3433

I tried to find solutions here but I couldn't find a post on AnularJS-WinJS binding problems with ListView.
In my project I use WinJS 4.4.0, AgularJS 1.4.8 and AngularJS-WinJS 4.4.0

All help is appreciated,
Arvid

Comment: when you changed your app.js you have removed win.js dependency injection

Comment: I've changed the content from only the changed code to the all the code from the app.js. The error is still there with the dependency injection in place.

Comment: When using the second solution you need to call the function: `custOverview.customerList()` (with the parenthesis). Not sure that helps you though. The error in solution1 means you have a binding that always change value when angular tries to read it, so it is never stable and the digest never finishes. Don't you have somewhere a code that would mofidy customerList ?